# detect mobile browser for a website using PHP

Tags: php, web, mobile

how can i detect if someone visits my website using safari or iexplorer via their mobiles?
i think the answer may be using the USER_AGENT variable, but i'm not really sure, so if you have a better idea or already a code running it would be just great to share :)

Comment: Instead of "checking" to see if it's mobile, the user would have to manually use the other address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Look at this:**

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

**PHP script:**

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/download/php

```
<?php

$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))

header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see that there two parts to this question

1. What fields do we use to detect the device type

   - User Agent Header
   - UAProf
2. How do we use these fields to find out the device type and the device characteristics.

For this you should have a device database that stores a mapping between the above mentioned fields and the corresponding device characteristics and also have an efficient algorithm to query this database.

Following could be your solutions.

- **build in house database and data access library** ( ***cons*** 
  re-inventing the wheel, problems with
  updating the database as and when new
  device come to the market, which
  practically is everyday )

  - **WURFL** ( ***pros*** contains both database and access library, open
    source, free, used to be the defacto
    standard till a few years ago and is
    very mature, ***cons***  is not always
    upto date)
  - **Device Atlas from .Mobi** ( ***pros*** uptodate, has efficient data access
    library, provides a wide range of
    device characterestics, IMHO best
    option | ***cons***  paid )

  BTW, Which language are you using to build you website ?

Comment: thanks for your answer man, as the question said i am using PHP and @naveed showed me a script that worked right away

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the browscap extension?

I use it with great success for detecting iPhone / other mobiles.

http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

The downside is that you need to manually update it from time to time (every couple of months or so)

or phpbrowscap if you dont have access to install extensions:

http://code.google.com/p/phpbrowscap/